# Send SMS via Journey builder- unable to render the header and footer in the message

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms, sendsmsactivity

I am sending an SMS message via the journey builder, so as per the docs I have created the SMS message under content builder and then using it with journey send sms activity.

Hereunder configuration setting of the SMS activity, I am selecting the 'from name' that I configured at the mobile connect, with that footer and header has also been configured.

So my issue is that if I select the 'from name', it should also consider the header and footer automatically in the SMS on delivery, but this is not happening. The header and footer are missing.

Is there anywhere else I need to configure header/footer for SMS journey send?

Answer (score 0):

The header and footer options are available for use only when sending messages from Mobile Connect. When using journeys, this does not happen. 
 The best option that you can go with is having a content block for your header and footer and include that in your SMS message using [ContentBlockbyId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyid.htm)